# Jquery/Javascript how to change button click function based on select option in dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a submit button which calls a specific method based on the selected `<option>` by the user.
The problem is both the previous and current addEventListener with their corresponding method gets called when I press the submit button. Both function one and two gets executed. I only want to execute functiontwo if the dropdown value is 2 and the user presses the submit button. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<select class="div-toggle" id="filter-list" data-target=".my-info-1">
    <option value="1" data-show=".1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-show=".2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<button  id="submitbutton">Submit</button>
```

JQuery/JavaScript:

I use the if pathname here because I use one general JavaScript file. If I declare the eventlistener outside functions I get undefined error on other pages because it can't find the element.

```
var btnsubmit = document.getElementById("submitbutton");


if (window.location.pathname=='/test/testpage.html') {
    $('#filter-list').on('change', function() {
        if(this.value == '1'){
            btnsubmit.addEventListener('click', functionOne);
        } else if(this.value == '2'){
            btnsubmit.addEventListener('click', functionTwo);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well if you want to do it _that_ way, then you obviously need to _remove_ the existing event handler, when you add the "other" one. Much simpler of course would be to use only _one_ event handler, assigned _one_ single time - and then from in there call either functionOne or functionTwo.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your method you can choise which function on button click base to select value like:

```js
document.querySelector('#submitbutton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  var valueSelect = document.querySelector('#filter-list').value;
  if (valueSelect === '1') {
    functionOne();
  } else {
    functionTwo();
  }

});

function functionOne(){
  console.log('one');
}

function functionTwo(){
  console.log('two');
}
```

```html
<select class="div-toggle" id="filter-list" data-target=".my-info-1">
  <option value="1" data-show=".1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-show=".2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<button id="submitbutton">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unsubscribe from the previously set `EventListener`.

Something like this:

```
        if (this.value == '1') {
            btnsubmit.addEventListener('click', functionOne);
            btnsubmit.removeEventListener('click', functionTwo);
        } else if (this.value == '2') {
            btnsubmit.addEventListener('click', functionTwo);
            btnsubmit.removeEventListener('click', functionOne);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$('#submitbutton').on('click', function() {
    if (window.location.pathname=='/test/testpage.html') {
       if($('#filter-list').val() == '1'){
          functionOne();
       } else if($("#filter-list").val() == '2'){
          functionTwo();
       }
     }
});
```